# Fatal Error: Function name must be a string in C:...... in line 6

Tags: php

Been finding answers in google just to find out how to fix this code but still cant fix it,
Really need some help

PHP Code

```php
/*-------------------------------Manage Connection-------------------------------------*/

    final public function connect($type)
    {
        global $core, $_CONFIG;
        if(!$this->connected)
        {
            $this->connection = $this->mysqli[$type]($_CONFIG['mysqli']['localhost'], $_CONFIG['mysqli']['root'], $_CONFIG['mysqli']['adventurer']);

            if($this->connection)
            {
                $mydatabase = $this->mysql['Habboretro']($_CONFIG['mysql']['Habboretro'], $this->connection);

                if($mydatabase)
                {
                    $this->connected = true;    
                }
                else
                {
                    $core->systemError('MySQL Engine', 'MySQL could connect to database');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $core->systemError('MySQL Engine', 'MySQL could connect to host');          
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: line 6 is which one?

Comment: What's the rest of the error message?

Comment: Should $mydatabase = $this->mysql be $this->mysqli? or is $this->mysqli meant to be $this->connection = $this->mysql

Comment: this one $this->connection = $this->mysqli[$type]($_CONFIG['mysqli']['localhost'], $_CONFIG['mysqli']['root'], $_CONFIG['mysqli']['adventurer']);

Answer (score 1):

Change your variadic function calls.  There are several ways.  Here is one approach:

This:

```
$this->connection = $this->mysqli[$type]($_CONFIG['mysqli']['localhost'], $_CONFIG['mysqli']['root'], $_CONFIG['mysqli']['adventurer']);
```

becomes:

```
$func = $this->mysqli[$type];
$this->connection = $func($_CONFIG['mysqli']['localhost'], $_CONFIG['mysqli']['root'], $_CONFIG['mysqli']['adventurer']);
```

Follow the same pattern for `Habboretro`.

Comment: Post line numbers, show the full error message, and document the PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

The Whole Php
Fatal Error: Function name must be a string in .......... in line 49

```html
<?php

namespace Revolution;
if(!defined('IN_INDEX')) { die('Sorry, you cannot access this file.'); }
class engine
{
 private $initiated;
 private $connected;
 
 private $connection;
 
 
 final public function Initiate()
 {
  global $_CONFIG;
  if(!$this->initiated)
  {
   $this->setMySQL('connect', mysql_connect);
   $this->setMySQL('pconnect', mysql_pconnect);
   $this->setMysql('select_db', mysql_select_db);
   $this->setMySQL('query', mysql_query);
   $this->setMySQL('num_rows', mysql_num_rows);
   $this->setMySQL('fetch_assoc', mysql_fetch_assoc);
   $this->setMySQL('fetch_array',mysql_fetch_array);
   $this->setMySQL('result', mysql_result);
   $this->setMySQL('free_result', mysql_free_result);
   $this->setMySQL('escape_string', mysql_real_escape_string);
   
   $this->initiated = true;
  
   $this->connect($_CONFIG['mysql']['connection_type']);
  }
 }
 
 final public function setMySQL($key, $value)
 {
  $this->mysql[$key] = $value;
 }
 
 
 /*-------------------------------Manage Connection-------------------------------------*/
 
 final public function connect($type)
 {
  global $core, $_CONFIG;
  if(!$this->connected)
  {
            $func = $this->mysqli[$type];
            $this->connection = $func($_CONFIG['mysqli']['localhost'], $_CONFIG['mysqli']['root'], $_CONFIG['mysqli']['adventurer']);
   
   if($this->connection)
   {
    $mydatabase = $func['Habboretro']($_CONFIG['mysql']['Habboretro'], $this->connection);
    
    if($mydatabase)
    {
     $this->connected = true; 
    }
    else
    {
     $core->systemError('MySQL Engine', 'MySQL could connect to database');
    }
   }
   else
   {
    $core->systemError('MySQL Engine', 'MySQL could connect to host');   
   }
  }
 }
 
 final public function disconnect()
 {
  global $core;
  if($this->connected)
  {
   if($this->mysql['close'])
   {
    $this->connected = false;
   }
   else
   {
    $core->systemError('MySQL Engine', 'MySQL could not disconnect.');
   }
  }
 }
 
 /*-------------------------------Secure MySQL variables-------------------------------------*/
 
 final public function secure($var)
 {
  return $this->mysql['escape_string'](stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($var)));
 }
 
 /*-------------------------------Manage MySQL queries-------------------------------------*/
 
 final public function query($sql)
 {
  return $this->mysql['query']($sql, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
 }
 
 final public function num_rows($sql)
 {
  return $this->mysql['num_rows']($this->mysql['query']($sql, $this->connection));
 }
 
 final public function result($sql)
 {
  return $this->mysql['result']($this->mysql['query']($sql, $this->connection), 0);
 }
 
 final public function free_result($sql)
 {
  return $this->mysql['free_result']($sql);
 }
 
 final public function fetch_array($sql)
 {
  $query = $this->mysql['query']($sql, $this->connection);
  
  $data = array();
  
  while($row = $this->mysql['fetch_array']($query))
  {
   $data[] = $row;
  }
  
  return $data;
 }
 
 final public function fetch_assoc($sql)
 {
  return $this->mysql['fetch_assoc']($this->mysql['query']($sql, $this->connection));
 }




}
?>
```

The Code is

```html
$this->connection = $func($_CONFIG['mysqli']['localhost'], $_CONFIG['mysqli']['root'], $_CONFIG['mysqli']['adventurer']);
```